# Vertical Text in Access 2003 Forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have been trying with no success lately to implement vertical text on an Access 2003 form im designing. There is a `vertical` option in the properties of every text box, but its not in the right direction. Text boxes marked with the attribute `vertical = true` start their text at the top side and then run downwards, exactly not as I want.

So my question is:

1. Is there native support for vertical textboxes other then the `vertical` attribute in Ms Access 2003
2. Failing #1, is there a way to shift text in text boxes by 180°.
3. Is #1 or #2 dependant on wether or not you have fixed text or text obtained from a data source.

Comment: You might be able to reverse your text string if you wanted the text to read from bottom up.  So 'Hello' would then be inverted to 'olleH'?  Just an idea, haven't tested it.

Comment: @Fink thats not what I want. I want it essentially to be the normal vert text but rotated 180°, as i've written above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft really messed this up by only implementing the one vertical direction, and not the other. :(

1. No
2. If you are desperate enough, you can try one of the solutions by the Great Wizard aka Stephen Lebans: http://lebans.com/rotatetext.htm or http://lebans.com/xrotatetext.htm
   There are other external solutions (commercial), like [Total Access Components](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/controls/components/rotated-text/index.html).
3. You'll have to try it out, but in comparison to the 90° rotation, making a label caption dynamic or giving a text box a constant text is trivial.